# If $\dim V =n$ and $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $T(W)\cap W \neq \{0\}$ for every isomorphism $T$ of $V$ then $\dim W \geq \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $\text{dim}\,V =n$ and $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $T(W)\cap W \neq \{0\}$ for every isomorphism $T$ of $V,$ then prove that $\text{dim}\, W \geq \frac{n}{2}.$

My attempt: By considering the restriction of $T$ to $W,$ we can see that $\text{dim}\, T(W) =\text{dim}\, W$ (since the kernel of the restriction equals $(\text{ker} \, T)\cap W = \{0\}$). By the given condition, $\dim (T(W)\cap W)\geq 1$ and since $\dim (T(W)+W) = \dim T(W) + \dim W -\dim (T(W)\cap W),$ we get  $\dim (T(W)+W)\leq 2 \dim W-1$ which, working backwards, seems to suggest that $T(W)+W$ is a hyperplane in $V,$ for every invertible operator $T$ on $V.$ But I'm not able to see this. I haven't yet used the fact that $T$ is onto either. Any hints on how to proceed, or whether this is the right track? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that you did use the fact it's unto when you said $dim(T(W)) = dim(W)$. That's only true if $T$ is both injective and unto $W$.

Comment: Would you please share the name of the book or material where you got this question ? I need to practice more questions like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove that for every $W$ such that $\dim W < \frac n2$, there exists an invertible transformation $T$ such that $T(W) \cap W = \{0\}$.

To do this let $w_1,...,w_k$ be a basis of $W$, where $k = \dim W$, and extend it to a basis $w_1,...,w_k,v_1,...,v_{n-k}$ of $V$.

Crucially, note that $k < n-k$.

Now, define $T$ as follows : $T(w_i) = v_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, then $T(v_i)= w_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, and amongst the rest of the vectors $v_{k+1},...,v_{n-k}$ , $T$ can be the identity i.e. $T(v_j) = v_j$ for all $k+1 \leq j \leq n-k$.

Then, $T$ can be extended linearly (it is enough to define $T$ on a basis).

It is seen by construction, that $T$ is surjective(therefore injective) and that $T(W) \cap W = \{0\}$.  Therefore, for $\dim W < \frac n2$, we always have a linear transformation that we do not desire. Now, it follows that if no such transformation exists, then $\dim W \geq \frac n2$.

For $n$ even, this can be strengthened to $\dim W > \frac n2$ by the same argument as above.

Comment: You're right because attempting the contrapositive gives us a concrete $T$ to work with. +1 for the tighter bound, nice example.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: I suppose you mean $W$ is the subspace generated by $(1, 0)$ or that $W $ is the subspace generated by $e_1$ instead of $W$ is the subspace generated by $(e_1, 0)$

Comment: You have proved that if there is an invertible $T$ such that $T(W) \cap W = \{\vec 0\}$, then $\dim W\leq n/2$, which is equivalent to the fact that if $\dim W> n/2$, then there is no such invertible $T$. But you needed to prove the inverse statement (up to the strictness of the inequality), that if there is no invertible $T$  such that $T(W) \cap W = \{\vec 0\}$, then $\dim W\geq n/2$.

Comment: @Litho Please check if it is correct now. That was a big lapse.

Comment: @AryamanJal There was a monumental error in the answer. I would like you to see the new answer. Indeed, I went the wrong way : I actually proved that if $\dim W > \frac n2$ then no such $T$ would exist, while I had to prove the converse statement.

Comment: Yes, now it's correct. Just a small typo: $k-1 \leq j \leq n-k$ should be $k+1 \leq j \leq n-k$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you, @Litho.

Comment: I see Litho's point, I didn't realise that your first answer actually proved the converse because it closely resembled my approach. Thanks for the edit, makes sense now

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг In fact the matrix of $T$ with respect to the (re-)ordered basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k, w_1, \ldots, w_k, v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_{n-k}\}$ is a block diagonal matrix where each of the three blocks is an identity matrix and will thus be invertible

Comment: @AryamanJal Yes, I think that makes the construction very canonical, in some sense. By the way, I have heard your name somewhere. Are you, by any chance, from Rishi Valley school?

Comment: Yes I am. Did you study there too?

Comment: So you are who I guessed you are! My name is Sarvesh. Sarvesh Iyer. I think I was two years your senior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68229/discussion-between-aryaman-jal-and----).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon how did you write  $T(w_i) = v_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, then $T(v_i)= w_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$,

Comment: @Chayan I'm checking,and I will get back to you in two minutes. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Chayan I am *defining* the linear transformation $T$ in that line. The point is, given a basis of a vector space, any linear transformation out of that vector space can be defined, by merely specifying the value of $T$ on every element that basis. Let me know if you want clarification on this. So in my case, I have *defined* with the basis $\{w_1,...,w_k,v_1,...,v_{n-k}\}$, the linear transformation given by $T(w_i) =v_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $T(v_i) = w_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Then, for the rest of the $v$s left over, I defined $T(v_j) = v_j$. So I get a linear transformation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yes now I got I initially thought that you were implying $T(v_i)=w_i$ from the definition that $T(w_i)=v_i$. So you need to write **and** instead of **then** in between these two. And can you suggest me a book where I can find more of such questions a bit more thinkable ones like this one.

Comment: @Chayan I believe this question is from Serge Lang's linear algebra?  That's a useful book, as is [this problem book of Halmos](http://dl.hamyarprojeh.ir/Halmos%20P.R.%20Linear%20Algebra%20Problem%20Book%20(MAA_%201996).pdf). Anyway, let me know your response, I'll respond tomorrow now. Thanks.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon this book by Serge Lang is very helpful, thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Chayan You're welcome! In general, I prefer to provide resources that are immediately available from the internet, so that's why I put the problem book up. It's also an excellent book, but offers a different way of learning when compared to a usual textbook.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon    Yes that is a great book I have been doing that for past 2 weeks and it gave me a lot of insights.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon can you please prove the converse, or give some hint to do that ?

Comment: @Chayan The converse is easy by the sum theorem : Suppose that $\dim W > \frac n2$ (note : I mentioned in the post above that from the hypothesis, we can actually prove that $\dim W > \frac n2$, so I'm starting with this premise). If $T$ is any isomorphism on $V$, then $\dim T(W) = \dim W > \frac n2$, therefore $\dim T(W) + \dim W > n$. But, we know that $\dim (T(W) \cap W) = \dim T(W) + \dim W - \dim(T(W) + W) > n-n > 0$ because $\dim(T+W) \leq n$ and the other sum is bigger than $n$. So, it follows that $\dim T(W) \cap W >0$, so $T(W) \cap W \neq\{0\}$. Similarly for the odd case.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you. Now it's pretty clear